# How do I collect the logged in user data from firestore and save it?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

After the user has logged in successfully I want to send the data to the getter of  class `Users` along with the unique key firestore generates, when I print the data of the logged-in user it's correct How can I do it?

```
static void getCurrentOnlineUserInfo() async {
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

    String userId = firebaseUser.uid;
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(userId)
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        userCurrentInfo = Users.fromSnapShot(documentSnapshot);
        print('Document data: ${documentSnapshot.data()}');
        print(userId);
      } else {
        print('Document does not exist on the database');
      }
    });
```

This is what I get when I print it `Document data: {phone: 12345678, name: test, email: test@gmail.com}` 
how do I set the `getter` in the user `class` ?

```
class Users {
  String id;
  String email;
  String name;
  String phone;

  Users({this.id, this.email, this.name, this.phone});

  Users.fromSnapShot(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    id = documentSnapshot.key;
    email = documentSnapshot.value["email"];
    name = documentSnapshot.value["name"];
    phone = documentSnapshot.value["phone"];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

oh wasn't that hard actually

```
class Users {
  String id;
  String email;
  String name;
  String phone;

  Users({this.id, this.email, this.name, this.phone});

  Users.getKey(String key) {
    id = key;
    print("Users $key");
  }

  Users.fromSnapShot(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    email = documentSnapshot.get("email");
    name = documentSnapshot.get("name");
    phone = documentSnapshot.get("phone");
    print("Users $email");
    print("Users $name");
    print("Users $phone");
  }
```